# When using `start-at-task` in Ansible, is it possible to force an earlier task to always be run?

Tags: ansible

I have a large complex Ansible provisioning setup, > 100 roles, > 30 inventory groups, etc... This is organised in the recommended way: top level playbooks, with a `/roles` folder, a `/group_vars` folder, etc...

Sometimes this fails part-way through, and I want to restart it from where it failed, using the `--start-at-task` command line switch.

However, I have several tasks that *always* need to run. These dynamically add hosts to the inventory, set variables that are needed later, etc...

Is there a way to force a task to *always* be run - or a role to *always* be applied, even when using `--start-at-task`?

I know about the `always` tag, but I think this only makes it run when filtering tasks by using `--tag`, not `--start-at-task` - unless someone knows differently?

Alternatively, is there some other way to structure things that would avoid this problem with `--start-at-task`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible.

Currently you either have to use tags or bite the bullet, rely on idempotency and let all tasks re-run.

---

There were [PRs](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/7039/files) and [discussions](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/10183#issuecomment-73481512) to add such a functionality, but they never made it to the official Ansible release.

There is also an [open issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12565) asking for this feature, with a suggestiion, that `always_run` should enable running the task when using in conjunction with `--start-at-task`, but the discussion also withered away more than a year ago.

Comment: I thought that was probably going to be the answer 

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion of the issue mentioned by `techraf` is that the good way to do it is by implementing a custom strategy: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12565#issuecomment-834517997

One has been implemented [there](https://gist.github.com/azertyfun/70b5341310840f92636ecf3ea2c3c6d3) (but I haven't been able to make it work with `ansible-test`)

Anyway it's a good start to implement a working solution and the only way possible as Ansible devs will not patch `--start-at-task`

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful!